# Show the count of Displayed results

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento, datepicker

we are using below code to filter rows based on selected From & To date.

we can able to filter successfully & displaying results.

**php**

```
/* to show selected date */

if (isset($_POST['post_at']) && $_POST['post_at'] != '')
    {
    $orderFromDate = $_POST['post_at'] . "  00:00:00 ";
    }
    else
    {
    $orderFromDate = '';
    }

if (isset($_POST['post_at_to_date']) && $_POST['post_at_to_date'] != '')
    {
    $orderToDate = $_POST['post_at_to_date'] . "    23:59:59  ";
    }
    else
    {
    $orderToDate = '';
    }

/* to show selected date end*/

function getDesignerCollection()
{
    /* date search */
    if (isset($_POST['post_at']) && $_POST['post_at'] != '')
        {
        $orderFromDate = $_POST['post_at'] . " 00:00:00 ";

        }
        else
        {
        $orderFromDate = '';
        }

    if (isset($_POST['post_at_to_date']) && $_POST['post_at_to_date'] != '')
        {
        $orderToDate = $_POST['post_at_to_date'] . "    23:59:59  ";

        }
        else
        {
        $orderToDate = '';
        }
   /* date search end*/

    $accountType = $rows['type'];
    if ($accountType == "admin")
        {

        if ($orderFromDate != '') $order->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array(
            'gteq' => $orderFromDate
        ));
        if ($orderToDate != '') $order->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array(
            'lteq' => $orderToDate
        ));
        }
```

**form**

```
<form name="frmSearch" method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" placeholder="From Date" id="post_at" 

    value="<?php

if ($orderFromDate != '')
    {
    $newPostStartDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['post_at']));
    echo $newPostStartDate;
    } ?>" name="post_at"  />  

<input type="text" placeholder="To Date" id="post_at_to_date" 


value="<?php

if ($orderToDate != '')
    {
    $newPostEndDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['post_at_to_date']));
    echo $newPostEndDate;
    } ?>"name="post_at_to_date"  />

<input type="submit" name="search" value="search" id="searchButton">

    <input type="button" value="Reset" id="clear-dates">
    </form>
```

**jquery**

```
jQuery.datepicker.setDefaults({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "assets/img/datepicker.png",
    buttonText: "Date Picker",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
});
$(function() {
    $("#post_at").datepicker();
    $("#post_at_to_date").datepicker();
});
```

[image]

now we want to display **how many rows are selected.** if result is as above image we want to display "rows : 1". i am very new to php & i tried below code , but its not displaying anything:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT entity_id , created_at  FROM sales_flat_order ORDER BY Name")) {

    /* determine number of rows result set */
    $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    printf("Result set has %d rows.\n", $row_cnt);

    /* close result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

**edit**

now we want to display **count of how many rows are displayed.**  so we tried below code. its displaying like below image. its displaying **"rows = 3"**. because its considering "entity_id" column of **"sales_flat_order"** table.  but i want **"rows : 9"** as you can see 9 rows in image.

[image]

[image]

```
require_once '../../app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

// specify the date picker date-format
$format = 'Y-m-d';


// if posted data are not empty
if(!empty($_POST['post_at']) && !empty($_POST['post_at_to_date']))
{

       if (!empty($_POST['post_at'])) {
           $dateFrom = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $_POST['post_at']);
       }

       if (!empty($_POST['post_at_to_date'])) {
           $dateTo = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $_POST['post_at_to_date']);
       }

        // Get the resource model
        $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');

       // Retrieve the read connection
          $read = $resource->getConnection('core_read');

      // MySQL query
        $query =  'SELECT entity_id, created_at, dproduct_id FROM sales_flat_order WHERE created_at BETWEEN :fromdate AND :todate ;';

// Bind MySQL parameters
$binds = array(
'fromdate' => $dateFrom->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
'todate' => $dateTo->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
);
// Execute the query and store the results in $results
$results = $read->fetchAll($query,$binds);
echo "rows : ".count($results);
echo "<br>";
print_r($results);
}


else {
echo "error you have not specified any dates";
}
```

complete code : http://pastebin.com/hMUEusvb

Comment: where is this code run? Is it definitely outputting to the part of the page you expect? I note it doesn't save the number and return it to the UI layer, it just prints it immediately. Search your page source for the string once it's rendered. And if it's not there, check your query actually returns results. Another way to do it would be a SQL Count() instead.

Comment: @ADyson seems i need to connect `search button` to end part of the code. am i correct ?

Comment: if you mean that the code needs to run when the search button is clicked, then yes.

Comment: @ADyson i have no idea on how to do that, can you please post an answer for that with code.....

Comment: you already have the code (assuming it's working, which it should)...you just need to make it run when the page is posted back. You just have to put it in the right place in your app (or call it from the right place). Your search button posts back to the server, right? At that point it runs some PHP code - maybe including the sample at the top of the question? You need to make your last sample run at the same time as this. I can't do that for you because I can't see the structure of the rest of your application.

Comment: @ADyson Yes, search button is connected to server as once we click on `search` button it display the `result` of particular `from & to date` , i will try what you said....

Comment: @ADyson  this is complete code of that file : http://pastebin.com/0x3375Mh , please check when you get free time....

Comment: I have checked your complete code. You do the count there, if I understood correct. There is the `$i` variable which counts the number of orders. You just need to pot it back to your UI. Can you integrate it in your `$responce` variable? Can you also post the code where you use it in your UI?

Comment: @moni_dragu Thanks a lot for your time, this is script and html code : http://pastebin.com/CPEjHm4h , can you please help me how i can `integrate $i in our `$responce` variable, in question i posted html code to display Date related UI [ `from & to date` & `search` button`,] i need result once i click on search button....

Comment: @moni_dragu please join chat here :  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130768/if

Comment: hi you use magento i think in this question you have to specify it.

Comment: To show how many rows are selected (checked) in the browser, you just count the checkboxes for how many are checked in that checkbox group.  jQuery's `.each()` plus some digging on checkbox `:checked` selector, should have you rolling in no time.

Comment: @SamuelJackson thanks, actually its showing number of rows, but not correct rows.... please check `edit` part of question once......

Comment: Found the problem.  This is .... Magento !!    You need to do some pretty funky stuff as working with raw tables doesn't work the same as they have links and stuff -- it's just a really wacky setup.  So things like Navicat/etc will understand the linking (and fail to backup),  but direct queries won't return desired results.  It looks like you are including Mage.php, and depending on their PDO calls .. maybe ?  i dunno.  Magento is what not to do with a filesystem, and security through obscurity  :)

Comment: @SamuelJackson you are right, as client wanted combination of php + magento- its killing me.....

Comment: If I may suggest,  adjust your question to note that it is using magento, and what your objective is using the magento api using php calls (3rd party script).  I am not versed enough to guide on that accord, but there are many on SO who are good with Magento's backend

Comment: @ADyson I really don't for get your help, Thanks.....

Comment: @moni_dragu I really don't for get your help, Thanks.....

Comment: @SamuelJackson I really don't for get your help, Thanks.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count number of rows by using js. Add following code at the end of your code. Replace selector1 with class name which is used only for rows. Inspect your page in browser and find a class which is present only in rows and used once at a time in a row.
Then replace selector2 with class or id where you want to display number of rows.

```
<script>    
$(document).ready(function () {
    var count = 0;
    //use class unique in each row.
    $("selector1").each(function () {
         count++;
    });
    //use class or id where you want to display count
    $("selector2").prepend("Number of rows "+count);
});
```

If you want to handle it done through PHP. Please paste the code where it renders the search result. 
Your current code is not working because your code send response back on line 293 of file http://pastebin.com/QKMj0k2p
You can find that in network tab of browser and see on search submit where it send request and what comes in response from there. If you can find where it is sending response back it will be easy to know which code is rendering rows. It will be more help full to solve your problem.

Comment: in magento `sales_flat_order` count will not match the rows in the view provided in the image. The results will be 3 orders (check order_id column). The canceled one is not being fetched by the query results.

Answer (score 2):

You can count the selected id from your mysqli query itsel.. Try this in your mysqli query

```
   if ($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT count(entity_id) as Total_count,entity_id , created_at  FROM sales_flat_order ORDER BY Name")) {
    // Your process
}
```

Comment: i tried your code, when i click on `search` button its displaying rows, but not displaying `how many rows` , can you please help me to connect `search` button to `end part of mycode` ? is that required ? or can we get the result with only `javascript`

Comment: please join here : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131215/date-search

Answer (score 1):

I think you have an error which is not present in your question. If you only want to fix this Issue. You can use JavaScript. You only have to know the exact selector.

```
$(document).ready( function (){
   //your selector would direct li or td if there is no other li td    then it works other wise you have select parent then li or td like below comment
   //$(".class li").length

   var count = $("li").length;
   $("yourCounter").html(count);
} );
```

Comment: Your Welcome Brother. Hope you pray for me. Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

your **PHP** code should be like this

```
// if posted data are not empty
if(!empty($_POST['post_at']) && !empty($_POST['post_at_to_date'])) { 
// specify the date picker date-format
  $format = 'Y-m-d';
// create dates
  $dateFrom = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $_POST['post_at']);
  $dateTo = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $_POST['post_at_to_date']);   
// if equal dates are applied to form 
  if($_POST['post_at']==$_POST['post_at_to_date']) {
    $dateTo->add(new DateInterval('T23H59M59S')); 
  }
// Get the resource model
  $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');    
// Retrieve the read connection
  $read = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
// MySQL query
  $query = 'SELECT `entity_id`, `created_at` FROM `sales_flat_order`  WHERE `created_at` BETWEEN :fromdate AND :todate ;';
// Bind MySQL parameters  
  $binds = array(
    'fromdate' => $dateFrom->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'todate' => $dateTo->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
);
// Execute the query and store the results in $results
  $results = $read->fetchAll($query,$binds);
  echo "Orders count: ".count($results);
} else {
  echo "error you have not specified any dates";
}
```

Comment: i got error as `Fatal error: Class 'Mage' not found in` line `$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');    `

Comment: may i ask what version of magento you have installed? @abcd

Comment: try adding this before `require_once 'app/Mage.php';`

Comment: now error : `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Name' in 'order clause'' in /var/www/html/sbdev2/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/sbdev2/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 /var/www/html/sbdev2/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array) #2 /var/www/html/sbdev2/app/code/core/Ze